# Yii2 Gridview - How use totals on footer property

Tags: php, yii2

My VALUE column is:

```
    [
     'attribute' => 'value',
     'format' => 'raw',
     'contentOptions'=>['style'=>'width: 10%;text-align:left'],
     'footer' => ???
    ],
```

How use totals of rows on FOOTER property ?

Comment: You can use this http://demos.krajee.com/grid to have most of what you want already built.

Comment: Sure, but natively there any correct way to do this without the extension?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

it's works
1. create class then 2.create column array, 3.configure column, 4.configure grid

```
namespace app\components;
class PTotal {
public static function pageTotal($provider, $fieldName)
{
    $total=0;
    foreach($provider as $item){
        $total+=$item[$fieldName];
    }
    return $total;
}
$provider = new ActiveDataProvider([
'query' => $query,
'sort' => $sort,
]);


$grid_columns=[         
[
    'attribute' => 'saldo_in',
    'footer'=>PTotal::pageTotal($provider->models,'saldo_in'),
]
]

echo GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $provider,
'showFooter'=>TRUE,
'footerRowOptions'=>['style'=>'font-weight:bold;text-decoration: underline;'],
'columns' =>$grid_columns,
]);
```

Comment: its works fine, i just create the function in my model class.. thanks Mihai and leonid

Comment: @leonid - I am also looking for total in footer in gridview. I just wanted to know which part of your above code will go in the class and view. Thanks.

Comment: I think that the option name 'footerRowOptions' is wrong, it should be 'footerOptions'.

Answer (score 4):

in the view file above calculate the footer sum by following code

```
    $amount = 0;
    if (!empty($dataProvider->getModels())) {
        foreach ($dataProvider->getModels() as $key => $val) {
            $amount += $val->amount;
        }
    }
```

now in your gridview use just pass the amount variable as follow

```
[
     'attribute' => 'amount', 'label' => 'Charged Amount',
     'value' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
              return Yii::$app->formatter->asCurrency($model->amount, 'INR');
              },
     'footer' => $amount,
   ],
```

i have tried it will work...

Comment: Just adding that it is still necessary to add:
'showFooter'=>TRUE,
at GridView::widget.

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried this but try defining the column like this.

On the top of the file define

```
$total = 0;
```

Afterwards define the column like this:

```
[
     'attribute' => 'value',
     'format' => 'raw',
     'contentOptions'=>['style'=>'width: 10%;text-align:left'],
     'value'=>function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) use ($total) {
        $total += $model->value;
        return $model->value;
     },
     'footer' => function () use ($total) 
     {
        //format the total here
        return $total;
     },
],
```

Now there are several problems with this as they are with the http://demos.krajee.com/grid meaning it will only add what it is shown, if you have pagination it will just show the total on that page.

If you want a total for all the records you should add it by hand using the dataprovider without pagination.

Again I have not really tried this, just give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

yii2 will not support  'footer' => function () use ($total)

- total for a column works like below for me in yii2 :

In your grid view, eg: for column total_hours you need to show footer with sum of this column total_hours then you do following by extend the column in gridview, declare variable total in above the page and start griview override column assign total pass by reference to add total_hours from each row or record and finally assign the value to gridview footer attribute.

```
                       [
                            'header' => 'total_hours',
                            'attribute' => 'total_hours',
                            'value'=>function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) use (&$total) {
                                $total += $model->total_hours;
                                $widget->footer = $total;
                                return $model->total_hours ;
                            },                          
                         ],
```

and add 'showFooter' => true,

Comment: Yes, use the ```use (&$total)``` to pass a variable through the functions. It can be useful without creating another function in the model. ```$widget->footer = $total;``` to store the variable

Answer (score 0):

i try as you say but show me the error: **trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given**

```
protected function renderFooterCellContent()
{
    return trim($this->footer) !== '' ? $this->footer : $this->grid->emptyCell;
}
```

In Yii 1 works fine, i just create this function in Model

```
public function getTotals($ids)
        {
            if($ids){
                $ids = implode(",",$ids);
                $connection=Yii::app()->db;
                $command=$connection->createCommand("SELECT SUM(value) FROM `tb_cashbook` where id in ($ids)");
                $amount = $command->queryScalar();
                return "R$ ".Yii::app()->format->formatNumber($amount);
                }
                else 
                return null;
        }
```

And in View, this way in footer property:

```
'footer'=>"<strong>".$model->getTotals($model->search()->getKeys())." </strong>",
```