# Yii2 : Get Sum In footer of gridview

Tags: gridview, yii, yii2, sum, yii2-advanced-app

I'm new here that I can't comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852453/yii2-getting-sum-of-a-column)

and I have a problem when I try to Get sum in the footer .

my code in controller :

```
$searchModel = new ReceiptsSearch();
$sum = new ReceiptsSearch();
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
 return $this->render('index', [
   'searchModel' => $searchModel,
   'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
   'sum'=>$sum,
   ]);
```

my SearchModel Code  :

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Receipts::find();
    $sum = $query->sum('price');
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }
    $query->joinWith('patient'); 
    $query->andFilterWhere([
       'id' => $this->id,
       'price' => $this->price,
       'reg_date' => $this->reg_date,
    ]);
    $query->andFilterWhere(['like','patient.patient_name',$this->patient_id]);

    return $dataProvider;$sum;
}
```

my view page

```
<?= GridView::widget([

    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,$sum,

    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'showFooter' => true,
    'columns' => [

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        [
        'attribute'=>'patient_id',
        'value'=>'patient.patient_name'
        ],
        'price',
        ],
        [
        'attribute' => 'sum',
        'footer' => 'sum',
        ],
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
    ]); 
?>
```

the message shown is :

> Setting unknown property: yii\grid\GridView::0

Comment: [This will help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28003381/yii2-gridview-how-use-totals-on-footer-property).

Comment: @InsaneSkull  I just wanted to know which part of that code will go in the controller or searchmodel and view .. how to use that solution .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Controller**

```
$searchModel = new ReceiptsSearch();
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

return $this->render('index', [
  'searchModel' => $searchModel,
  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
]);
```

**SearchModel**

```
public function search($params)
{
  $query = Receipts::find()->joinWith('patient');

  $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
  ]);

  $this->load($params);

  if (!$this->validate()) {
      return $dataProvider;
  }

  $query->andFilterWhere([
     'id' => $this->id,
     'price' => $this->price,
     'reg_date' => $this->reg_date,
  ]);

  $query->andFilterWhere(['like','patient.patient_name',$this->patient_id]);

  return $dataProvider;
}
```

**View**

```
<?= GridView::widget([
   'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
   'filterModel' => $searchModel,
   'showFooter' => true,
   'columns' => [
       ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

       [
         'attribute' => 'patient_id',
         'value' => 'patient.patient_name'
       ],
       [
         'attribute' => 'price',
         'footer' => Receipts::getTotal($dataProvider->models, 'price'),       
       ],

       ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

**Receipts Model**

```
public static function getTotal($provider, $fieldName)
{
    $total = 0;

    foreach ($provider as $item) {
        $total += $item[$fieldName];
    }

    return $total;
}
```

Comment: I told you before you are a genius, not Insane **it works as I want** :) .. thank you

Comment: @NaeemAli Told you i am insane, that's why genius. :)

Comment: you dont need the static method Receipts::getTotal Its enough to do it like this $dataProvider->query->sum('price') in your view file. thats even better cause it always use your current filter

Answer (score 2):

You can reach the same effect with `use kartik\grid\GridView;` without using helpers function.

Just add `'showPageSummary' => true` to your GridView config and `pageSummary' => true` to columns that you need to sum.

**View**

```
use kartik\grid\GridView;

echo GridView::widget([
       'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
       'filterModel' => $searchModel,
       'showPageSummary' => true,
       'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            [
                'attribute' => 'patient_id',
                'value' => 'patient.patient_name'
            ],
            [
                'attribute' => 'price',
                'pageSummary' => true
            ],
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
       ],
]); ?>
```

Comment: you answered my question after 1 year and 3 months :) , yeah you can do it  and i got this answer by experience :P

Answer (score 0):

The footer normally is intended  for a total  result for  a column (not for a separated column )

Assuming `$sum` is the value you want see  below the column price  you sould

```
 <?= GridView::widget([
  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider
  'filterModel' => $searchModel,
  'showFooter' => true,
  'columns' => [
      ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
      [
        'attribute'=>'patient_id',
        'value'=>'patient.patient_name'
      ],
      [
        'attribute'=>'price',
        'footer' => $sum,       
      ],
      ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
  ]); 
?>
```

But looking to your code you have several error  ..

In Search   this is wrong

```
 return $dataProvider;$sum;
```

You can return a value only so you should

```
  return $dataProvider;
```

In your controller this is wrong

```
 $searchModel = new ReceiptsSearch();
 $sum = new ReceiptsSearch();
```

The result for $sum is the same that for $searcModel   no new value is returned  for $sum

You should perform the query for  $sum this way

```
$sum = Receipts::find()->sum('price');



$searchModel = new ReceiptsSearch();
$sum = Receipts::find()->sum('price');
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
return $this->render('index', [
  'searchModel' => $searchModel,
  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
   'sum'=>$sum,
  ]);
```

Comment: still gives me `Setting unknown property: yii\grid\GridView::0`

Comment: 1) Remove the $sum form the 'dataProvider' row  like in my code  2) eventually Just for debugging  try comment  the  row  'value'=>'patient.patient_name'

Comment: @scaisEedge `trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`

Comment: looking to your code  i have see a some conceptual error ..try to correct these errors and then post the updated code

Comment: I used this way and its works fine , but it gives me the total of all data in Receipt table  even if I used filters , Thank you for your help

Comment: @NaeemAli   . your primary problem was the concectual error in your code .. the problem  of the total  in query is easly solved  using a function for calculate inside the gridview instead of  pass. the value in render call ..  but this was not clear in your code request ..

Comment: this is my fault ..  Sorry !